# In jQuery, why is $.clone(this) the same as $(this).clone()?

Tags: jquery

I actually made a mistake in the API call to [jQuery's `.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

Instead of using http://jsfiddle.net/AXsB5/17/ (you need to click in the fiddle to make the `.clone()` get executed):

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    var el = $(this).clone();

    el.css({ color: "orange" });
    $("#bar").append(el);
});
```

I mistakenly used http://jsfiddle.net/AXsB5/18/:

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    var el = $.clone(this);

    $(el).css({ color: "orange" });
    $("#bar").append(el);
});
```

The [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) would suggest that it shouldn't work for the second case.  I wonder why both cases worked?

Comment: I think documentation about jquery.clone is missed but applied in the library. And this should work as others lower level jquery like $.data().

Comment: where have they mentioned that second case should not work?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar because the API says .clone() can only accept a boolean (or 2 booleans) as an argument(s)

Comment: boolean means true or false but not meant to be there you should put only true or false. the object returned may be true or false.

Comment: @C-link but the API says you are not supposed to pass in an object -- only supposed to pass in boolean(s) -- of course unless if we say it is just not documented in the API docs, then it is another story

Comment: please try to understand the boolean means there not really boolean but object returning the boolean.

Answer (score 4):

According to [$ vs $()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/%3a):

> Until now, we've been dealing entirely with methods that are called on
>   a jQuery object.
>
> For example:
>
> `$( "h1" ).remove();`
>
> Most jQuery methods are called on jQuery objects as shown above; these methods are said to be part of the `$.fn` namespace, or the "jQuery prototype," and are best thought of as jQuery object methods.
>
> However, there are *several* methods that do not act on a selection; these methods are said to be part of the jQuery namespace, and are best thought of as core jQuery methods.
>
> This distinction can be incredibly confusing to new jQuery users.
>   Here's what you need to remember:
>
> - Methods called on jQuery selections are in the `$.fn` namespace, and automatically receive and return the selection as `this`.
> - Methods in the $ namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any arguments, and their return value will vary.

However, running through the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy_og_kush/AXsB5/20/) using a debugger, it seems it's never even getting to the `clone()` method on the `$.fn` namespace and is actually hitting `$().clone()`. This is probably due to it mapping `$().clone()` inside `$.clone()` (which runs when the jquery file is loaded) like in the source code linked above by *Arun P Johny*. I hope that makes sense... my advice is just to run through with a debugger to see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an internal method, not exposed to users(that might by why there is no api doc).

The .clone() method internally uses it, so both are the same

[jQuery.clone()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L148) and [.clone()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L397)

```
clone: function( dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents ) {
    dataAndEvents = dataAndEvents == null ? false : dataAndEvents;
    deepDataAndEvents = deepDataAndEvents == null ? dataAndEvents : deepDataAndEvents;

    return this.map( function () {
        return jQuery.clone( this, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents );
    });
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat unfamiliar to jQuery internal code... how come it looks like it is recursive?  That `clone()` is a function... that takes 2 arguments, and return `foo.map(fn)` where `foo` is the object that the `clone()` method is invoked on, and `fn` is `jQuery.clone()` itself...?  So that means... `bar.clone()` is the same as `jQuery.clone(bar)`?

Comment: @動靜能量 they are not recursive because both are 2 different methods... 1 is a plugin method where as other is a static method.. see the links attached in the answer

Comment: so you are saying `$("...").clone` and `jQuery.clone` are two different functions and they run different sets of code

Comment: so I think from the code above, we know `foo.clone()` returns `jQuery.clone(foo)`, so there, we establishes `$.clone(foo)` is the same as `foo.clone()`